# Get string between first and last occurrence of selected characters with C# in a performant way

Tags: c#

I have a string that can contain any characters, but I want the text between the first and last occurrence of characters.

Example string:

```
"x{1{hello}}y}z"
```

I want the string between the first `{` and the last `}`

Expected result:

```
"1{hello}}y"
```

Comment: Have you looked into using Regular Expressions for this?

Comment: @ADyson It was not clear in the question, but i need to be very performant. RegEx is not very fast. I will clairfy the question.

Comment: @AdrianRosca Some regex, if well formed and compiled, can be quite performant. We need a benchmark to really compare, but I'd suggest 1) to not rule out regex by principle, 2) provide some info about your performance requirements (size of input in number of lines / characters, and execution speed objective as order of magnitude)

Comment: @Pac0 Good point. 1) I kinda always rule out regex when I need performance. 2) The string are ~40kb and I need to process ~100-500 sec.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'm not sure RegEx and the 2 input strings will be performant enough. I can limit my case to 2 input chars.

Comment: @AdrianRosca The mentioned duplicate has 3 different answers

Comment: @AdrianRosca see my answer for benchmarks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netcore-3.1) method returns the index of the first occurrence of a specified Unicode character or string within this instance, and [`String.LastIndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netcore-3.1) method returns the index of the last occurrence of a specified Unicode character or string within this instance.

We can use [`String.Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) method which retrieves a sub-string from this instance:

```cs
string sourceString = "x{1{hello}}y}z";
string expectedResult = sourceString.Substring(sourceString.IndexOf("{") + 1, sourceString.LastIndexOf("}") - sourceString.IndexOf("{") - 1);

Console.WriteLine(expectedResult);
// Output:
// 1{hello}}y
```

We can use `string[index..index]` instead of `String.Substring` method:

```cs
string sourceString = "x{1{hello}}y}z";
string expectedResult = sourceString[(sourceString.IndexOf("{") + 1)..(sourceString.LastIndexOf("}") - sourceString.IndexOf("{") + 1)];

Console.WriteLine(expectedResult);
// Output:
// 1{hello}}y
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string s = "asdasd{1{hello}}y}zsd";
int first = s.IndexOf('{')+1;
int last =   s.LastIndexOf('}');
// classic
var expect = s.Substring(first, last-first);
// very nice way with c# 8:
var expect = s[first..last]
```

added the nice c# 8 range feature for the string

Bonus:
as I read from the comments of the Q, the author is aware of different performance in large data throughput scenarios. So I was curious and did Benchmarks:

the same with Benchmarkrunnter set on throughput:

```
Job=FastAndDirtyJob  IterationCount=2  LaunchCount=2  
RunStrategy=Throughput  WarmupCount=1  

|                  Method |            Mean |         Error |       StdDev |
|
------------------------ |----------------:|--------------:|-------------:|
|           WithSubstring |        22.82 ns |      6.173 ns |     0.955 ns |
|               WithRange |        22.91 ns |      4.382 ns |     0.678 ns |
|               WithRegEx |     5,153.74 ns |    112.028 ns |    17.336 ns |
|       WithRegExCompiled | 2,903,170.70 ns | 32,123.041 ns | 4,971.076 ns |
|         WithRegExInited |     1,967.75 ns |    196.775 ns |    30.451 ns |
| WithRegExCompiledInited |       848.55 ns |    110.135 ns |    17.043 ns |
```

`.Throughput` is the default [RunStrategy](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/choosing-run-strategy.html), works perfectly for microbenchmarking. It's automatically choosing the amount of operation in main iterations based on a set of pilot iterations. The amount of iterations will also be chosen automatically based on accuracy job settings. A benchmark method should have a steady state.

and the code:

```
void Main()
{
        var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<SubstringBenchmarks>();
    }
    
    
[SimpleJob(RunStrategy.Monitoring, launchCount: 5, warmupCount: 5, targetCount: 5, id: "FastAndDirtyJob")]
public class SubstringBenchmarks
{
    string s = "aasd{1{hello}}y}zsd";
    string reg =  @"(?<={).*(?=})";
    Regex rc;
    
    public SubstringBenchmarks()
    {
         rc = new Regex(reg, RegexOptions.Compiled );
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string WithSubstring()  
        {
        int first = s.IndexOf('{') + 1;
        int last = s.LastIndexOf('}');
        return s.Substring(first, last - first);
        }
        
        [Benchmark]
        public string WithRange() 
        {
            int first = s.IndexOf('{') + 1;
            int last = s.LastIndexOf('}');
            return s[first..last];
        }
        
        [Benchmark]
        public string WithRegEx()
        {
            var r = new Regex(reg);
            return r.Match(s).Value;
        }
        
        [Benchmark]
        public string WithRegExCompiled()
        {
            var r = new Regex(reg, RegexOptions.Compiled );
            return r.Match(s).Value;
        }
        [Benchmark]
        public string WithRegExCompiledInited()
        {
            return rc.Match(s).Value;
        }
}
```

Edit:
in the first answer I choosed a different, less appropriate benchmark run strategy: Monitoring.
According to the docs: If a benchmark method takes at least 100ms, you can also use the Monitoring strategy. In this case, the pilot stage will be omitted,

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.18363.900 (1909/November2018Update/19H2)

Intel Core i5-7300U CPU 2.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 2 physical cores    
.NET Core SDK=3.1.301
[Host] : .NET Core 3.1.5 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.26901, CoreFX
4.700.20.27001), X64 RyuJIT

Job=FastAndDirtyJob  IterationCount=5  LaunchCount=5   RunStrategy=Monitoring  WarmupCount=5  

|                  Method|         Mean |      Error |     StdDev |   Median  |
------------------------ |-------------:|-----------:|-----------:|----------
WithSubstring            |     4.524 μs |   2.322 μs |   3.099 μs |    3.700 μs | 
WithRange                |     3.536 μs |   1.784 μs |   2.381 μs |    2.600 μs |
WithRegEx                |    33.740 μs |   6.592 μs |   8.800 μs |    29.500 μs |       
WithRegExCompiled        | 3,337.984 μs | 380.808 μs | 508.367 μs | 3,214.100 μs |
WithRegExCompiledInited  |     8.780 μs |   2.551 μs |   3.406 μs |     7.700 μs
```

Comment: What is the name of `array[index..index]`? So I can to google it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges

Answer (score 1):

The next approach can be used to solve this problem:

```
string str = "x{1{hello}}y}z";
int start = str.IndexOf('{') + 1;
int end = str.LastIndexOf('}') - 1;
string substr = str.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "x{1{hello}}y}z";
        string Res = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('{') + 1, str.LastIndexOf('}') - str.IndexOf('{') - 1);
        return Res;
```